# [INS-30131]Initial setup required for the execution of installer validations failed. Encountering this error in Fedora 20

Tags: installation, oracle-12c

While I was installing Oracle 12c database on Fedora 20 I encountered this error which wasted my 2 days.

[image: This is the snapshot of the installation wizard]

"[INS-30131] Initial setup required for the execution of installer validations failed."

In the details it says this:

```
Cause - Failed to access the temporary location.  
Action - Ensure that the current user has required permissions to access the temporary location.  
Additional Information:
 - Framework setup check failed on all the nodes  
     - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available  
     - Action: User Action Not Available Summary of the failed nodes fedora   
 - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "fedora"  
     - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available  
     - Action: User Action Not Available
```

I have tried a lot of things like restarting the computer and changing the permissions of the tmp folder etc. But none of these methods worked.

Plz help me out from this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What guide are you following to install it on Fedora 20? It's not certified for that platform, and there will be steps you have to take to ensure the correct dependencies etc exist before you can even attempt to install Oracle on it.

Comment: I have followed this link for installing it on fedora 20: http://dbaora.com/install-oracle-12c-12-1-0-1-on-fedora-20/

Answer (score 3):

To see the real reason of this error in console output, use:

```
./runInstaller -debug -logLevel finest
```

In my case the reason was no execute permission for the file:
    '/tmp/CVU_12.1.0.2.0_oracle/exectask.sh'

So you simply need to add execute permission to all scripts and executable files in this directory, without exiting the installer.
Open the second console and use:

```
cd /tmp/CVU_12.1.0.2.0_oracle
chmod +x *.sh
chmod +x exectask
chmod +x cvuhelper
```

Then resume installation. It should install without further problems!

P.S.

Important remark about starting the database. It is not sufficient to use:

```
dbstart $ORACLE_HOME
```

and / or

```
lsnrctl start
```

You need to log in to the idle instance:

```
sqlplus SYS AS SYSDBA
```

and then use sqlplus command:

```
startup;
```

Then you can connect SYS@ORCL AS SYSDBA without error ORA-12514, assuming that you have set environment variable ORACLE_SID=orcl

Read also [Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/).